# IabHelper wrapper class of Googles In-App-Billing API in error conditions

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I'm trying to implement In-App billing functionalities into my app as suggested on https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/index.html. Nevertheless, in error conditions (at least network down will be a normal situation, product unknown, app version not matching to the one registered in developer console etc. might just be relevant during development) the    `IabHelper`    class responds with    `IabAsyncInProgressException`    on subsequent calls although the user gets information by google play store messages.
How do you handle this?
Thanks in advance, Dirk

Answer (score 0):

In between I found out, that activities    `onActivityResult`    method has to be implemented as shown on https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html (and also hidden somewhere but not mentioned in the *trivialdrivesample*).